# Converting Time Formats in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

How would I convert time values that are output in as a string (21m49s) into the Excel time value (00:21:49)? If there is no hour value to be given, the cell is not assigned a 0h value. It will display only minutes and seconds in that case.

Will also need to account for readings above 60 minutes which would display as 1h34m14s.

This is how I receive the time values:

[image]

This is what I need them to look like:

[image]

Comment: Check out the formula `=Time()`

Comment: first check the information you are receiving is an excel time value or if it is a string.  Simple test I usually use is `=isnumber(a1)1 where A1 is the cell I want to test.  if it comes back as true then its an excel time value most likely , if its false than its a string

Comment: if it an excel time value you need to format the cells for time.  look up custom cell formats.  If its a string you are going to need to rip out the numbers from the text and convert them value.  In this case look up RIGHT, LEFT, MID, and TIME functions for excel and it should give you some ideas.

Comment: also will you ever have a reading exceeding 60 minutes as that will change things as well.

Comment: @ForwardEd thanks for the help! Updated post with your questions. Looking into RIGHT, LEFT, MID now.

Comment: When you get those that are above 60 minutes, are the `65m30s` or are they `1h5m30s`?

Comment: @ScottCraner 1h5m30s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=TIME(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("h",A1)),LEFT(A1,FIND("h",A1)-1),0),IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("m",A1)),IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("h",A1)),MID(A1,FIND("h",A1)+1,FIND("m",A1)-1-FIND("h",A1)),LEFT(A1,FIND("m",A1)-1)),0),IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("s",A1)),IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("m",A1)),MID(A1,FIND("m",A1)+1,LEN(A1)-1-FIND("m",A1)),LEFT(A1,FIND("s",A1)-1)),0))
```

[image]

---

Though @Jeeped beat me, I will post my UDF:

```
Function TimeChange(str As String) As Date
Dim strArr() As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim hr As Integer
Dim min As Integer
Dim sec As Integer

str = Replace(str, "h", "h ")
str = Replace(str, "m", "m ")
str = Replace(str, "s", "s ")

strArr = Split(Trim(str))

For i = 0 To UBound(strArr)
    Select Case Right(strArr(i), 1)
        Case "h": hr = Left(strArr(i), Len(strArr(i)) - 1)
        Case "m": min = Left(strArr(i), Len(strArr(i)) - 1)
        Case "s": sec = Left(strArr(i), Len(strArr(i)) - 1)
    End Select
Next i

TimeChange = TimeSerial(hr, min, sec)

End Function
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Possibly as a VBA UDF¹.

```
Function realTime(str As String) As Double
    Dim t As Long, vTMs As Variant, vTMP As Variant

    vTMs = Array("h", 0, "m", 0, "s", 0)
    vTMP = Array(str & ChrW(8203))

    For t = LBound(vTMs) To UBound(vTMs) Step 2
        vTMP = Split(vTMP(0), vTMs(t))
        If IsNumeric(vTMP(0)) Then
            vTMs(t + 1) = Int(vTMP(0))
            vTMP(0) = vTMP(1)
        End If
    Next t

    realTime = TimeSerial(vTMs(1), vTMs(3), vTMs(5))

End Function
```

[image: realTme_UDF]

---

¹ <sub>A User Defined Function (aka UDF) is placed into a standard module code sheet. Tap <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> and when the VBE opens, immediately use the pull-down menus to **Insert ► Module** (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>,<kbd>M</kbd>). Paste the function code into the new module code sheet titled something like *Book1 - Module1 (Code)*. Tap <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to return to your worksheet(s).</sub>