# Convert String To Time Duration In Excel

Tags: excel

May I know the way to convert "1 h 49 m 57 s" to 1:49:57 in Excel. 
[image]
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use either a formula or VBA.  If you use a formula, the worksheet functions `LEFT`, `MID`, `SEARCH`, and possibly `SUBSTITUTE` should be useful.  There is plenty of information on string manipulations both on this site and on the Internet if you do an appropriate search.

Comment: Coincidentally, this was asked just yesterday and answered at [Converting Time Formats in Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36292174/converting-time-formats-in-excel/36293304#36293304).

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for your feedback. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this formula to replace letters to colons then convert text to value:
`=VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A5," h ",":")," m ",":")," s",""))`

After inserting the formula set the cell's number format to "time".

Comment: Thanks for your answer ;-)

Comment: HiHi Máté Juhász, if the format of the string is unpredictable, for example, it can be 1 h 37 m 6 s or 37 m and 6 s, can we change the format to 1:37:6, 0:37:6 and 0:0:6 respectively?