# Convert String To Time Duration In Excel In Any Of The Different Formats

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007, excel-2013

[image: Previous asked question]

I have asked a similar question on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36346973/convert-string-to-time-duration-in-excel), and the answer is accurate and efficient, but it only work when the input is

> `
>   1 h 1 m 1 s

format. If other formats, it will cause error.

The solution from the question

> `= VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A5," h ",":")," m ",":")," s",""))`

### -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

**My question as below:**

May I know the way to convert the following inputs to the expected output?

1. **1 h 48 m 5 s**  to **1:48:05**
2. **48 m 5 s** to **0:48:05**
3. **5 s** to **0:0:05**
4. **1 h 5 s** to **1:0:5**
5. Other combination of **h m s** to **0:0:0** format

Thanks in advance

---

Based on the two formulaes

> = SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("m",S32)),IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("h",S32)),"","0h"),"0h0m")&S32,"
>   ",""),"m",":"),"h",":"),"s","")*1

and

> =(IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("h",A1)),"0:","")&IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("m",A1)),"0:","")&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"h",":"),"m",":"),"s",""))+0

If the input is it

> `1 h 5 s`

it causes error.

The result should follow the test cases as below

[image: Test Case]

Comment: so how does the linked answer not work for situation 1. which you have provided as an example?

Comment: Beyond having *'asked a similar question'*, can you show any original effort that you have made (successful or not) towards a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way would be to add missing parts like:

```
=(IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("h",A1)),"0:","")&IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("m",A1)),"0:","")&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"h",":"),"m",":"),"s",""))+0
```

and then directly format it so it looks like you want it...

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if this answer is similar to the previous answer you received or not, but here it goes.

Lets assume your time string is in cell S32.  you will need to edit the formulas to suit your location.

We are going to need the TIME function which requires three arguments to be passed to it:

```
TIME(ARG1, ARG2, ARG3)
```

- ARG1 is an integer representing number of hours
- ARG2 is an integer representing number of minutes
- ARG3 is a number representing number of seconds

In order to determine the number of hours, check to see if there is an h in your source cell.  This can be done with the SEARCH or FIND functions.  They will return a number if the searched string is found and will return an error if it is not. We can use ISNUMBER function to determine if H has been found.

```
ISNUMBER(SEARCH("h",S2))
```

An IF function will be required to determine what value for the hour will be used.  The check from the formula above wil be the decision factor.  If h is there we can take the LEFT 2 characters with the LEFT function and get the hours.  If H is not found, then we will use 0 since there are no hours.

```
IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("h",S2)),LEFT(S32,2),0)
```

so now you have pulled out the hours or determine 0 if it there ae no hours.  We can apply the same process for minutes.  The difference is we will not be able to use the LEFT function.  Instead the MID function will be used.

In the case where there is an m determine where the m is with the search function,  then 3 character to the left of that start pulling character for a length of 2.  That will result in the number of minutes as showing in this formula below.  It also contains for IF function for the M check and returning 0 if it is not found.

```
IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("m",S32)),TRIM(MID(S32,SEARCH("m",S32)-3,2)))
```

Now working with the assumption that there is always s in your equation, the number of seconds can be determined by taking the last 4 characters, and then taking the first 2 character from the selected for.  This is done through nested LEFT and RIGHT functions as follows:

```
LEFT(RIGHT(S32,4),2)
```

Now since we have pulled a number for hours minutes and seconds, through equations can be used as the arguments in the time function as follows:

```
=TIME(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("h",S32)),TRIM(LEFT(S32,2)),0),IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("m",S32)),TRIM(MID(S32,SEARCH("m",S32)-3,2))),LEFT(RIGHT(S32,4),2))
```

### ALTERNATE FORMULA USING SUBSTITUTE:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("m",S32)),IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("h",S32)),"","0h"),"0h0m")&S32," ",""),"m",":"),"h",":"),"s","")*1
```

the final step regardless of your formula choice is to set the cell format to either a preset time that looks like you want, or in custom format you can set it to h:m:ss.  Your example does not show a leading zero in front of the hours or minutes but does for the seconds which is what that previous custom format will provide.  If you wish to be more consistant with your formatting and provide a leading zero to your minutes and hours when they are only single digit, choose hh:mm:ss as your formatting.

### PROOF OF CONCEPT

[image: Proof of Concept]

Dirk's formula is included in the image to show its working too.  Lots of options on how to convert.

Comment: Thanks for your detail explanation. The ALTERNATE FORMULA USING SUBSTITUTE is working from my side. Thanks for your answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

Put this standard formula in B2,

```
=IFERROR(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("h", A2)), TIME(--LEFT(A2, 2), --MID(A2, FIND("h", A2)+1, 3), --MID(A2, LEN(A2)-3, 2)),
         IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("m", A2)), TIME(0, --LEFT(A2, 2), --MID(A2, LEN(A2)-3, 2)),
         IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("s", A2)), TIME(0, 0, --LEFT(A2, 2)), ""))), "")
```

Format as Time (e.g. `h:mm:ss` ). Fill down.

[image]

Comment: Hi Jeeped, if the input is 1 h 33 s, the result is 1:33:33 and it's inaccurate

Comment: That does not follow your sample data formats. It should be `1 h 0 m 33 s`. If you want to just make stuff up that doesn't suit the code then please provide a full set of sample data together with expected results that you expect to meet your expectations.

Comment: The sample data have been uploaded. Thanks