# Converting a time format in excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to use the formaula provided here [Converting Time Formats in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36292174/converting-time-formats-in-excel/36293304#36293304) however the raw data i have is formatted with minutes indicated with ' and seconds with " e.g 5h 13’ 35” - i have tried substituting m with ' and s with " where referenced in the formula but I cant get it to work - could anyone please help me with that?

Simon

Answer (score 0):

When you do the replace, do make sure to remove the space. So, "' " should be replaced with "m". I think that should make the code work.

Comment: thats what I tried - replaced "m" with "'" and s with """

Comment: It will not work if you do the replace in the formula since """ is not a valid input. This is because the third " is ignored by the formula. Instead, are you able to replace ' and " in your data with m and s respectively?

Answer (score 0):

Format as Time and please try:

```
=1*(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"h ",":"),"’ ",":"),"”",""))
```

The `’` and `”` are the smart quotes versions.

Comment: Maybe it was excel correcting the copy from the sample but mine showed as a back-tick but a straight quote.

Comment: @pnuts thank you so much that worked really well - to further complicate things my data scrapes also give me the following variations in data - 4h23'00" & 5h 13’ 35”, 6'40" & 6' 40", and 7" & 5 " - sometimes the h can also be denoted by a t as well

Answer (score 0):

1. get rid of the seconds identifier (e.g. `"`)
2. change the minutes-with-space identifier to hour-with-space (e.g. `’` to `h`)
3. change hour-with-space to colon and use TIMEVALUE to get a real time.
4. format the result to Time

   ```
   =TIMEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2, CHAR(34), TEXT(,)), "’ ", "h "), "h ", ":"))
   ```

Note that you do not have a *tick* (e.g. `'`) in your example but a back-tick (e.g. `’`) identifying the minutes.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try the below formula,

```
=TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(146)&" ",":"),CHAR(148),""),"h ",":"),"hh:mm:ss")
```

This formula identifies the `'` and `"` with ascii values and replaced them finally giving you the time format. Hope this helps.