# Converting "##h ##m" to ##.## hours

Tags: excel, google-sheets, data-conversion, custom-functions-excel

My time tracking app exports employee hours in the following format:

`xxh yym`

I'm looking for a way to convert this into a decimal number of hours. For example,

```
input(06h 30m)
return(6.5)
```

Can't figure out a way to do it on Google Sheets or Excel. I tried creating a new function but it's well beyond my ability. I have very little coding experience.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Use left() to get the hours and then mid() to get the minutes which you divide by 60 to turn into a decimal then add to get the result.

Comment: see this then multiply the output by 24: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36292174/converting-time-formats-in-excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On **Google Sheets**, you can do this by the `REGEXEXTRACT()` builtin function as per the following formula (assuming your text is stored at `A1`)

`=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"^(\d{2})h \d{2}m") + REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"^\d{2}h (\d{2})m")/60`

> `REGEXEXTRACT()` is a regular expression extractor function. The input
>   text of `06h 30m` have the following pattern `^\d{2}h \d{2}m` where
>
> - `^` refers to start of the string
> - `\d` refers to single digit number, `\d{2}` means two digits
> - `h`, , `m` are all characters as they appear in the reference text.
>
> Hence, by using `()` around the portions we need to extract from the
>   text and simple arithmetic you can convert the `06h 30m` into `6.5`
>
> More information about regular expression syntax can be found in this
>   [tutorial](https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)

Comment: This did the trick! Thanks for your help. This will save me a few hours a month on payroll

Answer (score 2):

An alternative formula:

```
=24*TIMEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"m",""),"h ",":"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not totally sure what you mean by "input" and whether or not this is in a cell or a data source of some kind that you are parsing and it is unclear whether the "06h 30m" described is a time value in a cell with a custom format or if it is a text field.

This answer assumes that the data is a text field (in cell A2) and that you want to return the number as hours and fractions of an hour with a maximum of 24 hours (since I am also assuming that these are employee hours in a day).  It assumes that there is always a two-digit number of hours or minutes and that there is a single space between the xxh and the yym:

```
=TIME(LEFT(A2,2),MID(A2,5,2),0)*24
```

I hope this at least leads you in the direction you are trying to get to.

Answer (score 0):

```
Function ConvertTime(hours, minutes)
     return hours + (minutes/60)
End Function
```